# Can user be able to input any of array numbers and function outputs as if in a example below? (HTML and Javascript)

Tags: function

Is there a way to recreate this function to ask user to input in a "input text box" one of the array numbers like - 23.5 and then the function would output 39?

This is the html code:

```
  <label for="usr">Foot lenght (cm):</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control " id="usr">
```

And this is the script:

```
var shoeSizeMap = [
  { cm: '23.5', euroSize: '39' },
  { cm: '24.1', euroSize: '39' },
  { cm: '24.4', euroSize: '40' },
]


function findEuroSizeByCm(inputCm) {
  var result = shoeSizeMap.find(function(shoeSize) {
     return shoeSize.cm == inputCm;
  });
  return result;
}




(function () {
    var old = console.log;
    var logger = document.getElementById('log');
    console.log = function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arguments[i] == 'object') {
            logger.innerHTML += (JSON && JSON.stringify ? JSON.stringify(arguments[i], undefined, 2) : arguments[i]) + '<br />';
        } else {
            logger.innerHTML += arguments[i] + '<br />';
        }
      }
    }
})();



console.log(findEuroSizeByCm('23.5').euroSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to the input and get the input's value and pass it to the function. Then if the result is valid, console.log the euroSize.

Also, I didn't do anything with your console.log function is it wasn't relevant to the question.

```js
let usr = document.querySelector("#usr");
var shoeSizeMap = [
  { cm: '23.5', euroSize: '39' },
  { cm: '24.1', euroSize: '39' },
  { cm: '24.4', euroSize: '40' },
]


function findEuroSizeByCm(inputCm) {
  var result = shoeSizeMap.find(function(shoeSize) {
     return shoeSize.cm == inputCm;
  });
  return result;
}

function getSize(ev){
  let size = findEuroSizeByCm(ev.target.value)
  if(size)console.log(size.euroSize); 
}

usr.addEventListener("input",getSize);
```

```html
<label for="usr">Foot lenght (cm):</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control " id="usr">
```